# Annotation 230k images for YOLOv3

Tags: deep-learning, data-annotations, yolo

I have a image file that contains 230k image and I want to annotate these images in YOLO format but It's impossible to do this with my hands. What exactly should I do? Do you have any suggestion? I have been researching for many days but I can't any specific solution.